# "NoDefClassNotFound" and "T cannot not be resolved to a type", at runtime

Tags: java, runtime, classpath, runtime-error, classnotfoundexception

i'm struggling a bit here.
I have a java project in eclipse which contains a class (A) that uses 2 other classes (C1 & C2) each one of them is in a separated jar file (JAR1 & JAR2).
And in the same time C1 (JAR1) is also calling a method from C2 (JAR2).

- A (calls)

  - C1 (calls)

    - C2
  - C2

So i added both of the jar files in the runtime classpath of my project in eclipse, but at the execution (debug), when java is executing code inside the class A it sees both of the jar files and both of the classes C1 and C2, but when it entered inside C1 (which calls a method from C2) java could not see JAR2 and C2. I get "C2 could not be resolved to a type" and "NoDefClassFoundError".

BTW, the project compiles well, and both of the jar files are also in the buildpath.

Do you know what is the problem and how to solve it ?
Thanks

Comment: If you add both the jars in the build path. then it should work.

Comment: both the jars should be in class path.

Comment: They're already there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add both the Jars at.

`Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Add external Jars->Add.`

It should work then.

Comment: Please try it after a full build of the project.

Comment: Removed them, readded them, clean, build. Still the same problem.

Comment: Did you set to export it? It needs to be available at runtime as well, not only compile time.

Comment: Thanks Dr H, I've just set them to export, and now java sees the JAR2 and C2. But ... it raised another exception : UnsatisfiedLinkError. I'm investigating.

Comment: Have you set the java.library.path? If the jars are not on the classpath that is visible at runtime, you need to run your application with the switch -Djava.library.path="<path to your jar files>"

Comment: Yes, i think it finds the jar files now, but what is missing is a set of dll files. I've included them using -Djava.library.path=path\of_the\folder\that\contains\them and also by adding this folder to the runtime classpath (run configuration->classpath). But still UnsatisfiedLinkError

Comment: Are the necessary dll's where they can be found? (library path, classpath, Windows PATH, Windows/system32 etc.)

Comment: the dll's are in the path\of_the\folder\that\contains\them passed in arguments using -Djava.library.path and also added in Run Configuration->Classpath as a folder. Should i add them in the Windows PATH also ?

Comment: dll's are loaded using System.loadLibrary; it may be look for them somewhere else. You may also need to set the -Dlib.dir property. What does the stack trace say exactly?

Comment: So, i've finally been able to fix the issue thanks to you Dr H, and a collegue of mine. I just added the library_path to the windows PATH and it worked. Thanks again, and i accept your answer.

Comment: I mean Shreyos's, because the jar were in the Build Path but i needed to export them. But of course you helped me a lot Dr H, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `JAR2` to `JAR1`'s dependencies as well, not only to the main project that includes class `A`.

Comment: Ok, how to do that in eclipse, can we edit the dependencies of jar files ?

Comment: Yes, at Properties/Java build path/Libraries. Also, you may need to export it.

Answer (score 1):

Including Both Jars in buildpath should solve your problem(Project Properties ->Java build Path ->Libraries->Add External Jar)